# Relation of orbital speed and eccentricity

Tags: orbital-motion

Earth's eccentricity is 0. **0167** and [speed](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/our-solar-system/41-our-solar-system/the-earth/orbit/85-how-fast-does-the-earth-go-at-perihelion-and-aphelion-intermediate) at perihelion is 30.3 Km/s and at aphelion 29.3 with a difference of +/- 1. **0164** wrt average orbital speed

- Is this a coincidence or are the variations of speed directly related to eccentricity?
- can we calculate the time elapsed from aphelion,  knowing the eccentricity of the orbit?

Comment: Did you try to apply Kepler's laws (particularly the second) to the problem?

Comment: The free fall would be a special case for zero angular momentum i.e. when the orbit degenerates to a straight line.

Comment: It's given by Kepler's second law: A line joining a planet and the Sun sweeps out equal areas during equal intervals of time. The swept area is proportional to the distance times the orbital velocity: $dA=dt*v*r/2=const$. This makes the product of velocity and distance from the sun a constant. Is this what you are asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not a coincidence.

The linear eccentricity, $c$, is the distance from the centre of the ellipse to either of the foci. This diagram shows an orbit with this marked - for clarity I've made the orbit very eccentric:

[image: Eccentric orbit]

The eccentricity that you quote is defined as:

$$ e = \frac{c}{a} \tag{1} $$

where $a$ is the semi-major axis.

The lower diagram shows the Earth at its closest and most distant positions. These distances are:

$$\begin{align}
 r_{\text{max}} &= a + c \\
 r_{\text{min}} &= a - c 
\end{align}$$

Conservation of angular momentum tells us that:

$$ r_{\text{max}}v_{\text{max}} = r_{\text{min}} v_{\text{min}} $$

and therefore the ratio of the velocities is:

$$ \frac{v_{\text{max}}}{v_{\text{min}}} = \frac{r_{\text{min}}}{r_{\text{max}}} = \frac{a-c}{a+c} $$

Since equation (1) tells us that $c = ae$ the above equation simplifies to:

$$ \frac{v_{\text{max}}}{v_{\text{min}}} = \frac{1 - e}{1 + e} $$

Now we use the binomial theorem to approximate $(1 + e)^{-1}$ as $1 - e$ and this gives us:

$$ \frac{v_{\text{max}}}{v_{\text{min}}} \approx (1 - e)(1 - e) \approx 1 - 2e $$

where I've dropped terms in $e^2$ and higher powers on the grounds that if $e$ is small higher powers will be much smaller and can be ignored.

So does this work? Well, if we substitute your figures for the velocities we get:

$$ \frac{29.3}{30.3} \approx 0.967 \approx 1 - 0.33 \approx 1 - 2 \times 0.165 \approx 1 - 2e $$

And that's why the ratio of the velocities is related to the eccentricity.

Comment: @frank: calculating the time elapsed from aphelion requires solving the equations of motion and is a lot more complicated. Googling will find you [solutions for the two body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem).